# Switch a Task<T> where T is an enum

Tags: c#, enums, task-parallel-library

I want to get a `Task<T>` which is returned by a property.

```
enum ProgressStatus
{
   Success = 0,
   Failure
}

interface IMessage
{
   Task<ProgressStatus> AddMessage();
}

class Message : IMessage
{
   public Task<ProgressStatus> Add
   {
      get
      {
         return AddMessage();
      }
      set
      {
         Add = value;
      }
   }

   public async Task<ProgressStatus> AddMessage()
   {
      using (var db = new VinaChanelDbContext())
      {
         try
         {
            //do stuff...

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return ProgressStatus.Success;
         }
         catch { return ProgressStatus.Failure; }
       }
   }
}
```

My question is: How to `switch` property `new Message().Add`?

```
var msg = new Message();
switch (msg.Add) //this must be an enum instead of Task<enum>
{
   case ProgressStatus.Success:
      return Json(new { success = true });
   case ProgressStatuc.Failure:
   default:
      return Json(new { success = false });
}
```

Why must it be `Task<T>`? Because I want to use `async` and `await` inside method `AddMessage`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why is it generic if its constrained to a single Enum type?

Comment: Also, why return a `ProgressStatus` instead of creating a new exception for `ProgressError`?

Comment: Why bother using that `enum` instead of `Task<bool>`?

Comment: Why not just have a public property that you set the ProgressStatus to in the AddMessage() method and if the async operation hasn't completed yet, have it set to null or an equivalent enum value?

Comment: @Eris Because I don't know how to use an enumeration with string.

Comment: @juharr ya. I will improve it later. Thanks!

Comment: @CoryNelson Can it be an answer? I will upvote for you. Thanks!

Comment: @dustmouse Sorry, can you give me a demo?

Comment: @RonBeyer I wanna use `ProgressStatus` as a flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why must it be `Task<T>`?

To follow the chain, `Add` must be `Task<ProgressStatus>` because it returns `AddMessage();`, which is `Task<ProgressStatus>`.

> How to `switch` property `new Message().Add`?

To answer is as simple as "don't". Instead, `await` the `Task<ProgressStatus>` and use the result. A Task hasn't necessarily been run yet: the `await` indicates that the current code will wait for the task to be done.

```
ProgressStatus statusAfterAdding = await msg.Add;
switch (statusAfterAdding)
{
    // ...
}
```

You already use `await` with `await db.SaveChangesAsync();`, and this is the same thing: [`SaveChangesAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220070%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) returns a `Task<int>` which you `await` (although you ignore the returned `int`).

Comment: Thank you! Can I expand my question? If having an exception, how can I get/catch the error as a status?

Comment: `ProgressStatus` has 2 enumerators, can I add a new enumerator `Error` to catch exception as a flag?

Comment: @Mr.Wolf Do you have any reason to think you can't? I don't think this is very related to the question... if you can't figure it out, I think you could make a new question focusing on the code around `await db.SaveChangesAsync();`. Maybe I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: It's hard to me. Because the type of all enumerators are `int`. But it must be `string` if I wanna save an exception message. MSDN documents don't have any example to define an enumeration with string. :(

Comment: @Mr.Wolf Ah, it wasn't clear you wanted to pass a `string` instead of just another entry in the enum. To pass more data back, define a new class that can contain all the info you want, then pass that back instead of the enum. That's definitely not in the scope of the question.